# Solving $d \cdot a^4 - 2 \cdot d^2 \cdot a^2 + d^3 - a^2 = 0$ for $d$

Tags: systems-of-equations, factoring, golden-ratio

Can anybody help me with this equation? I can't find a way to factorize for finding a value of $d$ as a function of $a$:

$$d^3 - 2\cdot d^2\cdot a^2  + d\cdot a^4 - a^2 = 0$$

Another form:

$$d=\frac{a^2}{(a^2-d)^2}$$

Maybe this equation has no solution. I don't know. That equation is out of some calculus involving the golden number.

Thx for your help.

Comment: MathJax hint:  to get a centered multiplication dot, use \cdot to make d \cdot a and get  $d \cdot a$

Comment: Ok thx it is a bit verbose to write \cdot but ok I have done it.

Comment: If you want to find the value of $d$ in terms of $a$, what you have is basically a cubic with variable $d$ and coefficients involving $a$. Every cubic equation can be solved in terms of radical expressions, but the method to do so is rather tedious and involved. You might want to google for "general cubic solution" or "cubic formula".

Comment: It's quadratic in $a^2.$ That's a  bit easier than the fact that it's cubic in $d$ (which is unfortunately what you want to solve for). But maybe if one solves for $a^2$ it can give some insight that may help...

Comment: Ok thanks for the keywords I will search for that.

Comment: We sometimes see the period used even with numbers.  Is $2.3$ supposed to equal $6$ or $2\frac 3{10}?$  Yes, it is more characters, but it is the correct symbol.

Comment: @Stormer I've given you the steps to solve a cubic in my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're really keen on solving for $d$ in terms of $a$ and getting an explicit answer, there's no help for it except solving a cubic. I'm going to help take you through how to solve a cubic equation in general. Note that you'll have to plug in the actual values and work through the detailed algebra yourself.

So first note that your equation is a *monic* cubic in $d$. Monic means the lead coefficient is one. It's easy to make any cubic a monic by division, but since this is already in that form, it makes life a little easier.

Let's say you have a monic cubic $x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ (sorry about the re-use of $a$ here, but this is the form that I have handily written down when I worked out the solution and kept it in my google drive).

First step is to substitute $x = y-\frac a3$

That will allow you to reduce the equation to this form:

$y^3 + \alpha y + \beta = 0$.

where you can express $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in terms of the original coefficients. ($\alpha = b - \frac {a^2}{3}, \beta = \frac{2a^3}{27} - \frac{ab}{3}+c$, if you must know).

This form is called a *depressed cubic* as it lacks the square term. It's much easier to solve.

You now have to make the substitution $y = z - \frac{\alpha}{3z}$

That will reduce the equation to $z^3 - \frac k{z^3} + \beta = 0$.

(where $k$ is expressible in terms of $\alpha$. Again, if you must know, $k = \frac{\alpha^3}{27}$).

Finally substitute $m = z^3$.

This allows you to get to a quadratic:

$m^2 + \beta m - k = 0$

which can be solved exactly as $m = \frac{-\beta \pm \sqrt{\beta^2 + 4k}}2$

And of course, you can now work backwards: from $m$ to $z$ to $y$ to $x$.

As I said, very tedious, but doable.

The alternative, as mentioned in the comments is to express $a^2$ in terms of $d$ using the quadratic formula, but this may not be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thx for your answer !

Comment: You're welcome. ;)

Answer (score 2):

The equation can be rewritten as 
$$d^3-2a^2d^2+a^4d-a^2=0,$$
which is a cubic in $d$. This can be solved by applying [Cardano's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano_formula) to the depressed cubic
$$d^3-2a^2d^2+a^4d-a^2=x^3-a^4x+a^2\left(\tfrac{26}{27}a^4-1\right),$$
where $x:=d-\tfrac23a^2$. Then
$$x=\frac{a^{2/3}}{3\sqrt[3]{2}}\sqrt[3]{27-26a^4+\sqrt{568a^8-1404a^4+729}}+\frac{a^{2/3}}{3\sqrt[3]{2}}\sqrt[3]{27-26a^4-\sqrt{568a^8-1404a^4+729}},$$
where the cube roots are of real numbers if and only if
$$568a^8-1404a^4+729\geq0,$$
or equivalently $\left|a^4-\frac{351}{284}\right|\geq\frac{81}{284}\sqrt{3}$. Then $d=\frac23a^2+x$.

Comment: Thx for your answer !